# What classical pieces are references in Michael Kamen's orchestral score for Last Action Hero?

Tags: classical-music, soundtrack, influence

The film [Last Action Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Action_Hero) makes several meta references to its own film genres and to classical music and literature (*Shakespeare, Mozart, Vivaldi, Dracula* among others...), merrily mixing cartoon characters with film noir, fantasy with drama, comedy, action and philosophy into a very layered result.

The [Michael Kamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Kamen) score matches this by combining hard rock and heavy metal influences with several famous classical pieces, to match the action or paraphrase it as it happens on screen (*Mozart, Vivaldi, Prokofiev*...). The combination results in what is, to me, one of the most genius and underestimated film soundtracks ever.

I have been looking for a long time for references documenting what is borrowed from classical works, and how it relates to the multi-layered narrative of the film, but haven't been able to find anything, since the film and its score fell into disinterest following the film's disastrous performance at the box office, and are now unjustly treated as an ugly duckling.

### What are the classical music references in this soundtrack?

<sub>(Since two soundtrack albums came out, I need to precise again that I'm not talking about the soundtrack that contains the metal songs, but [the orchestral Michael Kamen soundtrack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000029BY) with the white background cover art - not on spotify or itunes).</sub>